# What is the filename of SQLite for Windows Runtime 3.7.15.1?

Tags: sqlite, windows-runtime, installation, windows-store-apps

I have two apps that have problems compiling since getting the latest (3.7.15.1) version of SQLite.

The second one has been "on the back burner" until this morning, so I didn't notice it until now.

On trying to compile, I get: "*Could not find SDK "SQLite.WinRT, Version=3.7.15.1*".

The list of References does show that I have "SQLite for Windows Runtime" installed.

I just realized, though, that the properties are:

```
(Name)  SQLite for Windows Runtime
Fiel Type   SDK
Identity    SQLite.WinRT, Version=3.7.15.1
Path    [blank]
Resolved    False
Version 0.0.0.0
```

These last three are probably the problem (no path, unresolved, no version info). So somehow, apparently, the Path, etc., wasn't added when installed. So what is the filename of the SQLite for Windows Runtime, so that I can search for its location and manually add that to the path (at which point the Resolved and Version info will hopefully get added, too).

### UPDATE

I find sqlite3.dll here:

*C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0\ExtensionSDKs\SQLite.WinRT\3.7.15.2\Redist\Debug\x86*

Is that the appropriate file (sqlite3.dll) and location to add to Path?

### UPDATE 2

So much for that idea: the "Path" property is not editable.

### UPDATE 3

Looking closer at the file path, I see that what I have installed is 3.7.15.2, not 3.7.15.1.

The three possible versions of SQLite I saw in "Recent" were 3.7.14, 3.7.15, and 3.7.15.1. Once I went to the "Extensions" tab, I found 3.7.15.2.

The Path it added is: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0\ExtensionSDKs\SQLite.WinRT\3.7.15.2\ (so there is no "\Redist\Debug\x86" appended)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say from you question whether you're still having a problem with this or not, but even if it works for you now, the following might by useful for someone who will stumble across this question.

The reference to SQLite is always added through the `Windows > Extension` part of the `Add Reference...` dialog. When you add the reference, it is always added to the version of the SDK that was installed at the time.

The SDK is managed and updated through `Extensions and Updates...` dialog, including the notifications when a new version of the SDK becomes available. Once you update the SDK through this mechanism, the old version of the library is not available any more. Any projects that still reference it will fail to build with the error which you have encountered as well:

```
Could not find SDK "SQLite.WinRT, Version=#.#.#.#.
```

To resolve the problem you need to remove the existing reference and add it again through the `Add Reference...` dialog. This way the reference will be updated to the latest version of the library which is available on your machine and the project will build once again.

There is a side effect of this process when a team of multiple developers is working on a project referencing SQLite. As soon as one of them updates the SDK and the reference in the project and commits this change to source control, all of the developers will have to update the SDK before they will be able to build the project again.

Also in the `Windows > Recent` part of `Add Reference...` dialog old versions of the SDK which you have previously added to projects remain listed even after the SDK is updated to a new version. This means that you can still add it from here but it won't work since the library is not there any more. Unfortunately Visual Studio doesn't remove such references from the dialog even when you try to add them nor does it warn you about the problem in any other way than the failing build. You can remove the reference from the dialog yourself, though, by right clicking on it and selecting `Remove from Recent References`.

Comment: Thanks, Damir; your last paragraph was the pertinent one. I finally realized that my latest installation was not to be found on the "Recent" tab, and was able to fix it.